# Add Curl query to Elastic cloud watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to create following alert in Elastic cloud:

- Raise alert if number of unallocated shards exceeds 'x' value.

According to elastic-cloud documentation we can use the following query to Inspect unallocated shards:

`GET _cat/shards?v=true&h=index,shard,prirep,state,node,unassigned.reason&s=state`

Can this query be implemented using a elastic watcher?
I have tried to implement using following code. I am unable to figure out the condition part:

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "http": {
      "request": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "some-host",
        "port": 9243,
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/_cluster/stats",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {},
        "auth": {
          "basic": {
            "username": "user-name",
            "password": "some password"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "source": "def nodes = GET _cat/shards?v=true&h=index,shard,prirep,state,node,unassigned.reason&s=state {if (nodes > 300) {return true;}} return false;",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "send_email_alert": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "to": [
          "me@examplemail.com"
        ],
        "subject": "Shard Alert",
        "body": {
          "text": "The number of shards per node exceeds 300. Please investigate."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to elastic cloud and have reached an impasse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_cluster/health` API call to see the number of unassigned shards. Here is all available [watcher HTTP input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/input-http.html) if needed.

You can use `ctx` to access and use the value of any output. In your case we can use `ctx.payload.unassigned_shards`.

```
"condition": {
  "compare": {
    "ctx.payload.unassigned_shards": {
      "gt": 4
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information about `ctx` and how watcher works? in the following link.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html

### Here is the full example:

```
POST _watcher/watch/_execute
{
  "watch": {
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "http": {
      "request": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "cluster-id",
        "port": 9243,
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/_cluster/health",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {},
        "auth": {
          "basic": {
            "username": "::es_redacted::",
            "password": "::es_redacted::"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "condition": {
      "compare": {
        "ctx.payload.unassigned_shards": {
          "gt": 4
        }
      }
    },
  "actions": {
    "send_email_alert": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "to": [
          "::es_redacted::"
        ],
        "subject": "Shard Alert",
        "body": {
          "text": "The number of unassigned shards is {{ctx.payload.unassigned_shards}} and it exceeded 3. "
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

### Here is the email as output:

```
The number of unassigned shards is 5 exceeded 3.
```

---

**Important note:** Please control your `ES_URL` and make sure you can see the expected output with `curl` command before working on watcher. Eg.

```
musab@musab-mac Desktop % curl -k "https://your_cluster_name.es.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243/_cluster/health?pretty" -u username:password
{
  "cluster_name" : "0ce67bce635a4b3882c580678b5cb4f5",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 720,
  "active_shards" : 720,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 5,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 99.3103448275862
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou I used your answer as reference and it worked for me.